# INDEX MATCH 2 Column Criteria [Partial Match + Full Match]

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

There is a sheet called "Bookings".

Column H reflects their role

- SALES
- RECEPTIONIST
- SALES AND RECEPTIONIST

---

In the current sheet:

- Column J, it is a Qualification role e.g. "SALES" or "RECEPTIONIST".

---

How can I amend the following code on index match to pull over only staff from "Bookings" who partial match Column J?

If someone's role is "SALES", I can get it to pull over "SALES".
If someone's role is "RECEPTIONIST", I can get it to pull over "RECEPTIONIST".
However, if it is "SALES AND RECEPTIONIST" as the role, it fails to pull over whether it is "SALES" or "RECEPTIONIST".

Please advise how I should amend the Formula below.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Bookings!$B:$B, 
MIN( 
IFERROR(MATCH(1,($N3=Bookings!$C:$C)*($J3=Bookings!$H:$H),0),1E+99), 
IFERROR(MATCH(1,($N3=Bookings!$D:$D)*($J3=Bookings!$H:$H),0),1E+99), 
IFERROR(MATCH(1,($N3=Bookings!$E:$E)*($J3=Bookings!$H:$H),0),1E+99), 
IFERROR(MATCH(1,($N3=Bookings!$F:$F)*($J3=Bookings!$H:$H),0),1E+99), 
IFERROR(MATCH(1,($N3=Bookings!$G:$G)*($J3=Bookings!$H:$H),0),1E+99)

 )))
```

Comment: Share a copy of sample sheet.

Comment: Instead of `range=value` use something like `=FILTER($B$2:$B$4,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(J2,$H$2:$H$4)))` https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfDId.jpg

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: You can try with wildcards too... Like instead of searching "SALSES", search for " * "&"SALES"&" * " , basically enclosed the search value with asterisk...

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your statement (your question needs some clarification):

> If someone's role is "SALES", I can get it to pull over "SALES". If
> someone's role is "RECEPTIONIST", I can get it to pull over
> "RECEPTIONIST". However, if it is "SALES AND RECEPTIONIST" as the
> role, it fails to pull over whether it is "SALES" or "RECEPTIONIST".

Your are looking for a filter condition that considers an `OR` condition in case your are looking for both roles. Here is how you can do it on cell `F3` (see the screenshot below):

```
=LET(result, FILTER(C3:D20, 
  (C3:C20<>"") * (IF(A3="SALES AND RECEPTIONIST", 
  (D3:D20="SALES") + (D3:D20="RECEPTIONIST"), D3:D20=A3))), 
  IF(A3="","", result))
```

You can consider more than one filter condition via [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) function. Simulating `AND` condition with multiplication (`*`) and `OR` condition with addition (`+`). Each condition evaluates to `0` or `1`, for the same range of the first input argument of `FILTER`, so this is how you achieve it. I excluded empty rows to consider a more general case. The [LET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) function is used for easy reading. Here is the screenshot:

[image: sample excel file]

In the cell `A3` I have a list (*Data->Data Validation->Allow* with the option *List*) with the following values:
`SALES,RECEPTIONIST,SALES AND RECEPTIONIST`, so you can dynamically filter by your roles.

I hope it helps to use it on your real problem.